# Correct way to reference another method in an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code below works, but my gut tells me this isn't the most succinct way to do this. I'd like to use `this.function2()` instead of `videoControler.function2()`, but that doesn't work. Is this the best way to write this?

```
const myController = {
  function1() {
    return res.json({
        blah: myController.function2()
    })
  },
  function2() {
    return "blah"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers

Comment: And what error did you get, when you try to use this?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, replacing myController to this will point to currect scope, so it will not work. You should bind function1 to myController, and create reference to this outside the return state object, like const self = this;

Answer (score 0):

Definitely check out @Teemu's link in the comment but another way to handle this is by using classes.

For instance:

```
class myController {
  constructor(type) {
    this.controllerType = type;
  }

  function1(x) {
    return res.json({
        blah: this.function2()
    });
  }

  function2(x) {
    return "blah";
  }
}
```

And this would follow the properties of OOP where you can instantiate a `new myController("video")` object and invoke functions belonging to the class, outside the class as well.